# select from different table on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
ABC (id, type_id, x, y, z)
```

and these 5 tables:

```
 x(id, title, address_id, my-X-Related-Values)
 y(id, title, address_id, my-Y-Related-Values) 
 z(id, title, address_id, my-Z-Related-Values)
 address(id,address)
 type(id,title)
```

x,y,z of ABC refer to x.id , y.id, z.id.

NOTE that in each row of ABC only x or y or z has values in it and others are NULL.

type table:

1. `id:1 ---- title:'hello x'`
2. `id:2 ---- title:'hello y'`
3. `id:3 ---- title:'hello z'`

I have done this so far but don't know how to continue for y and z tables:

```
SELECT ABC.id ,type.title AS type,address.address FROM ABC
INNER JOIN address,type,x,y,z
WHERE ABC.x = x.id AND 
address.id = x.address_id
```

**EDIT :** 
i have these six queries that i want to execute in only one query:

```
            $string = "SELECT melk_standardize.melk_id ,bongah.title AS bongah,deal_type.title AS deal,apartment.address AS address,melk_types.title AS type FROM melk_standardize
INNER JOIN bongah,apartment,deal_type,melk_types WHERE melk_standardize.apartment_id = apartment.apartment_id AND bongah.id = apartment.bongah_id AND deal_type.id = apartment.deal_type AND melk_types.id = 1 ORDER BY apartment.apartment_id";
            $string = "SELECT melk_standardize.melk_id ,bongah.title AS bongah,deal_type.title AS deal,apartment_presale.address AS address,melk_types.title AS type FROM melk_standardize
INNER JOIN bongah,apartment_presale,deal_type,melk_types WHERE melk_standardize.apartment_presale_id = apartment_presale.apartment_presale_id AND bongah.id = apartment_presale.bongah_id AND deal_type.id = apartment_presale.deal_type AND melk_types.id = 2 ORDER BY apartment_presale.apartment_presale_id";
            $string = "SELECT melk_standardize.melk_id ,bongah.title AS bongah,deal_type.title AS deal,house.address AS address,melk_types.title AS type FROM melk_standardize
INNER JOIN bongah,house,deal_type,melk_types WHERE melk_standardize.house_id = house.house_id AND bongah.id = house.bongah_id AND deal_type.id = house.deal_type AND melk_types.id = 3 ORDER BY house.house_id";
            $string = "SELECT melk_standardize.melk_id ,bongah.title AS bongah,deal_type.title AS deal,garden.address AS address,melk_types.title AS type FROM melk_standardize
INNER JOIN bongah,garden,deal_type,melk_types WHERE melk_standardize.garden_id = garden.garden_id AND bongah.id = garden.bongah_id AND deal_type.id = garden.deal_type AND melk_types.id = 4 ORDER BY garden.garden_id";
            $string = "SELECT melk_standardize.melk_id ,bongah.title AS bongah,deal_type.title AS deal,shop.address AS address,melk_types.title AS type FROM melk_standardize
INNER JOIN bongah,shop,deal_type,melk_types WHERE melk_standardize.shop_id = shop.shop_id AND bongah.id = shop.bongah_id AND deal_type.id = shop.deal_type AND melk_types.id = 5 ORDER BY shop.shop_id";
            $string = "SELECT melk_standardize.melk_id ,bongah.title AS bongah,deal_type.title AS deal,ground.address AS address,melk_types.title AS type FROM melk_standardize
INNER JOIN bongah,ground,deal_type,melk_types WHERE melk_standardize.ground_id = ground.ground_id AND bongah.id = ground.bongah_id AND deal_type.id = ground.deal_type AND melk_types.id = 6 ORDER BY ground.ground_id";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add separate joins for each table and specify the condition for each join.  I'm assuming that you want to join on x, y, and z with ABC is ANY of x, y, or z match.

Not sure this will give you exactly what you want, but I think it's close.

```
SELECT ABC.id AS id, type.title AS type, address.address AS address
 FROM ABC
    JOIN address ON (ABC.id = address.id)
    JOIN type ON (ABC.id = type.id)
    JOIN x ON (ABC.x is NULL OR ABC.x = x.id)
    JOIN y ON (ABC.y is NULL OR ABC.y = y.id)
    JOIN z ON (ABC.z is NULL OR ABC.z = z.id)
```

Comment: thx for the reply. but the problem is that each ABC record identifies which  table to use for comparison in join: x, y or z. when the table is identified then i can check the value because i have other columns to work with too.

Comment: OK, think I understand. So you want the columns from either x, y, or z, depending on the value of x, y, or z column in ABC?  If, x, y, z have the same columns, or  the columns you want from each have the same data type, you could do it using UNION.  Think I may need more specifics about what data you have and what you want the result to be.

Comment: I've edited the question for better result. thanks again for your concern

Comment: whoa, could use a bit of formatting... anyway, so you are picking address from one of 5 tables.  Assuming address has the same data type for all 5 of them, the simplest change is to use UNION, but it is still essentially 5 queries, only difference is DB server is combining the results into a single result instead of you doing it.  If that's OK, then try it.  If you want just a single SELECT, I have some thoughts, but it depends on whether each row in melk, will there be only one address entry (e.g. if apartment.address matches a row, will this row not have a matching entry in others?

Comment: sorry but I wrote the question in a symbolic format at first to make the understanding better.   the melk_standardize table is only a table to gather all the data in other 6 tables and give a different id to each record. the only difference in these selects is that i want to use different tables for different rows of melk table. every melk_id is generated differently for each type. for example if it is an apartment then there is a row added to the table with these values: ap_100 as melk_id, 1 as type,100 as apartment_id which is the same as apartment.apartment_id,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,...